# python web.py execute external program asynchronously

Tags: python, linux, web.py

I have a web.py application running on built in cherrypy server.
I want to execute an external script when user post to an url, and the script will run in the background in a python subprocess.Popen call and web.py will redirect to another page where the progress of the script is being monitored using a jquery ajax request.
But I'm unable to properly implement this here.
the code snippets are as follows, I can provide more information if needed.

```
        import web
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import subprocess, shlex
    import time, json
    from login import authorize, sessidGen

    def __callProcess(processString,mod='w',shell=False):
        if not shell: args = shlex.split(processString)
        else: args = processString
        out = open('./bteq/logs/output.log',mod)
        err = open('./bteq/logs/error.log',mod)
        p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=out,stderr=err,shell=shell)
        return p

    def setExec():
        __callProcess("chmod +x ./bteq/*.sh",shell=True)

    def bteqExec(filename,system):
        if system not in ['prod','da','cdw','cdw2','cert','']: return False
        processString = " ".join([filename,system])
        p = __callProcess(processString)
        return p.pid

    render = web.template.render('templates/',base='layout')
    render_plain = web.template.render('templates/')

    class Executor:     
        def GET(self):
            authorize()
            session = web.ctx.session
            inputs = web.input(sessid={},type={})
            if not inputs.sessid or session.id != inputs.sessid: web.seeother('/')
            if inputs.sessid and inputs.type:
                return render.executor('BTEQ Executor',inputs.type,inputs.sessid)
            else: raise web.seeother('/')

        def POST(self):
            authorize()
            session = web.ctx.session
            inputs = web.input(sessid={},type={},act={})
            if not inputs.sessid or session.id != inputs.sessid: web.seeother('/')
            if inputs and inputs.act == 'start':
                pid = bteqExec('python ./bteq/timer.py','')
                session.id = sessidGen()
                session.exctrpid = pid
                return web.seeother('/progress.htm')
            else: raise web.seeother('/')

    class progress:
        def GET(self):
            authorize()
            session = web.ctx.session
            inputs = web.input(ajax={})
            if inputs.ajax == 'true': 
                web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                if session.count >= 100: session.count = 0
                session.count += 10
                pid = session.exctrpid
                out = open('./bteq/logs/output.log','r')
                err = open('./bteq/logs/error.log','r')
                output = ('<strong>OUTPUT:</strong><br>'+out.read()).replace('\n','<br>')
                err = err.read()
                if err:error = ('<strong>ERRORS:</strong><br>'+err.read()).replace('\n','<br>')
                else: error = None
                d = {'count':session.count,'msg':output,'err':error,'rc':pid,'session_id':session.session_id}
                return json.dumps(d)
            r = web.template.Template('$def with (title)\n$var title: $title\n')
            return render_plain.layout_pgbar(r('progress test'))
```

Since subprocess.Popen object is not pickleable it is not able to be put in as a session variable, and I want to the p.poll() and p.stdout.read() from the progress class.

Also I want the code runnable in both linux and windows, I have my dev setup in windows and I deploy it on linux servers.

Could someone help me out here...

Thank you.

Comment: In the actual application I'm not running **"python ./bteq/timer.py"**, I'm running a Teradata bteq script.

Comment: I made a multiprocessing wrapper to call the subprocess. This is working fine but, I wanted to know if there is a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it into a *multiprocessing* **Process** and do the *p.wait()* for the *subprocess* from the spawned Process, and spawned process take care of rest of the steps and update results into database.

The web.py progress page will check in the database for the progress of execution and thus it is solved.

code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class ProcHandler(Process):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        #Initialize 
        Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        p = bteqExec('python ./bteq/timer.py','')
        rc = p.wait()
        # do update the resulting to database. and make the web.py 
        # Progress class read from database entry made by this Process.
        return
```